# pardot and google analytics

Tags: tags, pardot

Hi I recently switched over to pardot but since then have noticed all our conversions in google analytics is showing up as direct/(none) instead of google, facebook, linkedin etc.

further investigation has led me to believe that when I submit a form on my landing page aaa.bbb.com it redirects it to go.bbb.com before finally loading the thank you page at aaa.bbb.com/thank-you.

pardot had us set up a cname so go.pardot.com now goes to go.bbb.com.

anybody have any thoughts? I have tried cross domain tracking via GTM with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a cross domain tracking issue because the domain (bbb.com) stays the same.  The issue is the *subdomain* - a different visitor ID is being created at each subdomain.

The solution is to add your domain to the Referral Exclusion list.  You can either do this in your Google Analytics account, or in GTM.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830

Comment: Thanks for looking into this andrew but I already tried that solution without any luck.

Comment: Are you using the traditional code on your site (ga.js) or universal analytics (analytics.js)?  If the former, you need to use the setDomainName function:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the `parent.postMessage()` function from the iFrame to track Pardot iFrame based form completions in Google Analytics and keep your original traffic source/medium and not the Pardot form URL.

In your Pardot form builder completion actions tab you'll have to add code that let's the iFrame parent (your website domain) know that the Pardot form has successfully been submitted. You then can use GTM to listen for this event and trigger a Google Analytics tag to fire when the Pardot lead form has been completed.

Here is a step by step guide Pardot iFrame Form tracking in Google Analytics